# What to do when integral in derivation diverges?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration

I am currently looking at the second virial coefficient for  a square well potential

$$
U(r) = \begin{cases}
\infty & r < \sigma \\ 
-D & \sigma < r <\lambda \sigma \\ 
0 & r>\lambda \sigma \end{cases}
$$

The second virial coefficient is given by

$$
B_2(T) = 2\pi \int_0^{\infty} \left( 1 - e^{-U(r)/kT} \right) r^2 \text{d}r
$$

By splitting up the range of integration, expanding the paranthesis and sorting the integrals, I obtain

$$
B_2 = 2\pi \left[ \int_{0}^{\sigma}r^2 \text{d}r + \int_{\sigma}^{\lambda \sigma}r^2 \text{d}r + \int_{\lambda \sigma}^{\infty}r^2 \text{d}r - \int_{0}^{\sigma}r^2e^{-U(r)/kT} \text{d}r - \int_{\sigma}^{\lambda\sigma}r^2e^{-U(r)/kT} \text{d}r - \int_{\lambda\sigma}^{\infty}r^2e^{-U(r)/kT} \text{d}r \right]
$$

The third term will diverge. So how can I continue to get a closed expression for the second virial coefficient? Also, in evaluating the integrals which contain the exponential term, can I insert the value for $U(r)$ before doing the integration, since this will simplify things for when $U(r) = 0$ and $U(r) = \infty$?

Comment: Your conditions don't look correct. The top line should be $r < \sigma$?

Comment: Fixed. I just realized, if I insert values for $U(r)$ before expanding the paranthesis, some of the integrals will be zero. That might work.

Comment: Bingo. $1-\operatorname{exp}(\ldots)$ has to vanish for $r\rightarrow \infty$ because $U\rightarrow 0$ (ie the interaction cuts off). It's only a question of whether it vanishes fast enough to suppress the volume element $r^2\operatorname{d}r$ in the integral.

Comment: don't expand the paranthesis, just split the integration domain into three and plug in the values for $U(r)$